# ActiveRecord mapping to table name with schema name as prefix

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

Has anyone experienced this issue on mapping table in ActiveRecord when table name need a schema name as a prefix (oracle)?

1. Gemfile

   ```
   gem 'activerecord', '4.2.4'
   gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.6.7'
   ....
   ```
2. db_helper.rb

   ```
   class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
       self.abstract_class = true
       self.table_name_prefix = 'OPT_ABC.'
       self.table_name = 'STUDENT'
       def self.list_student
         puts Student.take(1)  #testing
       end  
   end
   ```
3. The actual table name looks like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM OPT_ABC.STUDENT;
   ```
4. I am able to connect to the database instance, but when the code gets line:

   ```
   puts Student.take(1) # SELECT * FROM STUDENT LIMIT 1
   ```

   I get the following error:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
   table or view does not exist: SELECT "STUDENT".* FROM "STUDENT"
   ```

I am looking for solution on how to handle 'OPT_ABC." table prefix. Please share your solution.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to use both `self.table_name_prefix=` and `self.table_name=` together when you should be using one OR the other.

First let's consider how both `self.table_name_prefix=` and `self.table_name=` work.

---

#### self.table_name_prefix=

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name), `self.table_name_prefix=` works by prepending the passed in value to the table name that ActiveRecord automatically generates based off of the name of the class.

So, if the class name is `Student` and you do `self.table_name_prefix = 'OPT_ABC.'`, your table name will be `OPT_ABC.STUDENTS`. Note that the generated table name is plural (and ends in an `s`).

#### self.table_name=

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D), `self.table_name=` sets the table name explicitly. This means that it completely overrides the table name to the value that you pass in.

So, if you do `self.table_name = 'OPT_ABC.STUDENT'` your table name will be `OPT_ABC.STUDENT`.

---

So, given that, to set the table name to `OPT_ABC.STUDENT`, you should be able to simply pass the value into `self.table_name` like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    self.table_name = 'OPT_ABC.STUDENT'
    def self.list_student
      puts Student.take(1)  #testing
    end  
end
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! I tried your suggestion. But I got the following error:

Comment: Thank you Scott! I tried your suggestion. But I got the following error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
table or view does not exist: SELECT "OPT_ABC"."STUDENT".* FROM "OPT_ABC"."STUDENT" WHERE ROWNUM <= 1. Any thoughts? Thanks!